# Extracting price from html tag in website that uses same tags for everything

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm going to post this question and answer tomorrow, as it's 2am here... So sorry in advance.

I'm web scraping from this particular page:[Italian Website](https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/roma/parioli-flaminio/?criterio=rilevanza)

What I'm having difficulty with is the scraping of information that is between tags that have been used many time, basically making them 1 in 1000.

Here is the part of code I need (I need the price):

```
<ul class="listing-features list-piped">
    <li class="lif__item lif__pricing">
                    € 1.340.000
                </li>
```

And here is the code where I get the information from the same website, literally one tag above, but this one has a singular type and it's easy to find.

```
while pagina <= temp:
    if pagina == 1:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(userurl).content, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.select("[data-row-link]"):
            list_links.append(link["href"])
            list_titles.append(link.get_text(strip=True))
        #-----------------
        for link in soup.select(("lif__pricing")):
            list_prices.append(link.get_text(strip=True))
        #-----------------
        pagina += 1
    else:
        userurl = userurl + "&pag=" + str(pagina)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(userurl).content, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.select("[data-row-link]"):
            list_links.append(link["href"])
            list_titles.append(link.get_text(strip=True))
        # -----------------
        for link in soup.select(("lif__pricing")):
            list_prices.append(link.get_text(strip=True))
        # -----------------
        pagina += 1
```

The ------ are used to show you guys which lines are dedicated to get the price info I wrote above. So everything inside that is what is giving me head injuries and bashing my keyboard syndrome.

Now I'll crash into my bed and oblivion, please help me not fail!

Comment: I'm sorry if I will answer tomorrow, I'm really just tried of this problem. Thanks and sorry again!

Comment: `for link in soup.select(".lif__pricing")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to crawl all pages and extract links, titles and prices + create a dataframe and save it to csv:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/roma/parioli-flaminio/?criterio=rilevanza&pag={page}"

list_links, list_titles, list_prices = [], [], []
page = 1
while True:
    print("Page {}...".format(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url.format(page=page)).content, "html.parser"
    )

    links = soup.select("[data-row-link]")
    if not links:
        break

    for link in links:
        l, t, p = (
            link["href"],
            link.get_text(strip=True),
            link.find_next(
                class_=["lif__pricing", "lif__pricing--wrapped"]
            ).get_text(strip=True, separator=" "),
        )

        list_links.append(l)
        list_titles.append(t)
        list_prices.append(p)

        print(l, t, p, sep="\n")
        print("-" * 80)

    page += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "title": list_titles,
        "price": list_prices,
        "link": list_links,
    }
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
Page 1...
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/87572320/
Trilocale piazza Pitagora, Parioli, Roma
€ 660.000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/87574354/
Bilocale piazza Perin del Vaga, Flaminio, Roma
€ 430.000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/87573756/
Trilocale piazza Pitagora, Parioli, Roma
€ 660.000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/87578264/
Appartamento via Gaetano Donizetti 20, Pinciano - Villa Ada, Roma
€ 695.000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Then saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]